# Data Retention Policies in Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am new to this Azure Data Lake world. I am looking for any necessary pre-requisites and considerations in-order to use azure data lake. I found a good link for this and found quiet useful.
  http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2016/7/31/data-lake-use-cases-and-planning

right now, one thing which I am not sure about is data retention policies with in Data lake. Some people say that data shouldn't be deleted/purged from data lake while few has very different opinion.

So, are there any specific and basic considerations which we need to follow for data retention policies (archival, purge) with in any data lake?. I understand that use cases would be the deciding factor in this regard, but are there any high level considerations to make before deciding on this, is my question.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your major factors are:

1. Is there a legal obligation to expire data?
2. Is there a cost reason to expire data?
3. Is there a staleness factor where you do not care about the old data anymore (and are willing to be proven wrong in the future)?

Answer (score 0):

Pricing could also be a factor:

10TB on Azure Data Lake Store - $390/month

10TB on Azure Blob Storage - $152/month

As far as issues related to fragmentation with deletion, similar to an RDBMS data warehouse, I'm not aware of any.

Melissa Coates did a great job on that article from last October.  Thanks for sharing that.